# splitViewController showDetailViewController without animation?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I was just wondering if it's possible to show a detail view controller without it animating in (sliding into the window from the right). I'm expecting there to be some sort of animated boolean parameter, but it seems like there isn't.

This is all I have:

```
[self.splitViewController showDetailViewController:detailViewController sender:self];
```

Am I missing something here? Or is there no way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using the class method `performWithoutAnimation` on `UIView`, for example:

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    [self showDetailViewController:_detailedViewController sender:self];
}];
```

Comment: Worked for me with `-[showDetailViewController:sender:]` being called on a `UISplitViewController`, a `UIWindow` root view controller. (As of iOS 10.3.)

Answer (score 0):

Two options: You could use a delegate to load the view controller instead.  You would need to implement the `splitViewController:showDetailViewController:sender:` method.  Alternatively, (though the docs seem to discourage this) you could just assign your new detailViewController to the splitViewController's `viewControllers` property directly:

```
NSArray *vcArray = @[self.splitViewController.viewControllers[0],detailViewController];
self.splitViewController.viewControllers = vcArray;
```

Technically you should check to ensure that the existing viewControllers array has two elements first.